# postgresql pg_dumpall password error

Tags: postgresql, backup

postgresql 9.4 following this cheat sheet http://www.postgresonline.com/special_feature.php?sf_name=postgresql90_pg_dumprestore_cheatsheet&outputformat=html trying to backup

[image]

here is my command

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin>pg_dumpall -h arcserver -U postgres -w -p 5433 -f "R:\Data\LUCZ_2017\PostgreSQL_Backup\lucz.sql"
```

then it gives me this strange error

```
pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "template1": fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

what is template1? as you can see in the picture there is no template1?

I put in the -w so it doesnt ask me for the password..

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you think you don't have a template1 db? What does `psql -l` show you?

Comment: sorry still getting used to DB's. yes it is there when I run psql \l but why does it not show up in pgadmin?

Comment: but when the password prompt comes it does not let me enter anything...?

Comment: How does it stop you?

Answer (score 0):

pg_dumpall will try to dump the entire cluster (all databases that the engine serves). If you need this functionality, you probably only want to dump your lucz database (I'm assuming). Try using the -d option to specify the database to dump.

For help:

```
pg_dumpall --help
```

or https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pg-dumpall.html